# Facing Problems Saving Image on Heroku Application

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I'm currently writing a Heroku server in Python, and the purpose of the server is to read base 64 and then convert it to an image on my filesystem. However, I'm facing trouble with this (encountering an internal server error), and can't find anything similar online. The following in my code (which was saved in app.py, and Procfile is just web: python app.py).

EDIT: By the way, I don't actually have an AI.png for some reason .. its not saving on my file system.

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from base64 import decodestring
from PIL import Image
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def work():
    b64 = request.args.get('img')
    fh = open('AI.png', "wb")
    fh.write(b64.decode('base64'))
    fh.close()
    im = Image.open('AI.png')
    pix = im.load()
    width, height = im.size
    return "Image received: " + str(width)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Can anyone help diagnose the problem? BTW, this probably isn't that relevant to the problem, but here is my requirements.txt:

Flask==0.9

Jinja2==2.6

Werkzeug==0.8.3

wsgiref==0.1.2

Pillow==3.3.0

Comment: Each Heroku dyno has its own file system that goes away when the dyno does. If you need access to the files outside of the dyno or for longer periods of time, you'll need to store the files elsewhere, [such as S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3).

Comment: OK, but can you tell me why the above code isn't working? I'm writing to AI.png on the dyno's file system, and then opening it and trying to get the width. It is still giving an internal server error.

Comment: The best way to get help with that is to put the full traceback of the actual error in your original question. "Internal server error" doesn't give any information that could help. Since you're using Heroku, the necessary information should be in your Heroku logs.